# Traverse and enrich downloaded XML in React-Native-SVG

Tags: javascript, xml, react-native, react-native-svg

In my app I have the following:

```
axios.get( '/game' ).then( ({ data }) => this.setState( { game:data } ) )
...
render() {
  const { game } = this.state
    
  return <View>
    {game && <SvgXml xml={game}/>}
  </View>
}
```

That works like a charm so far.

Now I want to add stuff like `onPress`-listeners to certain elements of the SVG and also to analyze the content of the XMl, for example, to count the specific items.

Is there a way to accomplish that out-of-box?

Comment: Not out of the box, but you could use a library like fast-xml-parser. Then either map through the xml and create it piece-by-piece or use it to create Pressables in the right spots and render the whole svg the way you are now.

Comment: yeah, that's the only other option.